# Autoconf - use macro from m4/revision.m4 in AC_INIT arg list

Tags: autoconf

OK, I have a file m4/revision.m4 which has the macro REC_SVN_REV defined. I would like to use that in the version info in AC_INIT in configure.ac. But is it OK to call AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) before AC_INIT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no need.  Invoke `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR` after `AC_INIT` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m4_include([revision.m4])
AC_INIT([*******], [svn[]REC_SVN_REV], [i****@b*********.com], [*******-prealpha])
```

Works fine!